# what are the real time benefits of migrating to service bus 12c from 11g for an enterprise application?

Tags: weblogic, soa, weblogic12c, osb, oracle-fusion-middleware

What are the real time benefits of migrating to service bus 12c from 11g for an enterprise application? We are currently using soa suite 11g. One thing which I know is it incorporates the development of services in jdeveloper itself instead of using eclipse. 
Also, approximately how much time is required for the migration?

Comment: Note that you can still use Eclipse in 12C, it's just less supported than JDev. Of course, given JDeveloper's long history of being buggy and unstable, it might be a compelling option.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the benefit that I have found is the native support for REST Services and the use of JS for REST end to end services in OSB 12.2.1 and SOA 12.2.1.

The migration time is highly dependant on the number of services you have in both OSB and SOA, but it must be quite simple.

Comment: Thanks @Carlos Flores